# Java - Como habilitar o deshabilitar un botón desde otra clase

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy aprendiendo Java y me he encontrado con un problema.
No encuentro la manera de modificar la propiedad de un objeto desde otra clase.

Por ejemplo, tengo un formulario con un boton de abrir. Este botón abre otro formulario y se deshabilita el propio botón. Desde el segundo formulario con un botón de cerrar, cierro este segundo formulario para volver al primero y ... habilitar el botón que previamente deshabilité.

Pero no encuentro la manera de acceder al botón del primer formulario desde el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

La manera de acceder a una propiedad de una clase **X** desde otra **Y** seria instanciando la clase que usaras y llamando su atributo; en este caso pongamos nombre a los dos formularios que tienes, Formulario1 y Formulario2.

```
Formulario2 f2 = new Formulario2();   //Creas una instancia.  
f2.NombreDelBoton.setEnabled(true);  //Activas el boton.
```

Hay que recordar que el boton tiene que tener un acceso **public** cuando lo declares para poder acceder a él de esta manera, sino tendrías que crear un getter/setter.
Sin embaro de esta manera no estarias accediendo al primer formulario sino crearías otro y como nunca ocultas el primer no vale crear otro, yo te recomiendo usar un Control para manejar todo sin tener que crear cada vez que des click un objeto.
Si no entiendes muy bien dejame un comentario o puedes buscar directamente como trabajar MVC(modelo,vista,control).

```
public class Control implements ActionListener {

    Panel1 p1; //formulario 1
    Panel2 p2; //formulario 2  

    //Constructor que recibe los formularios  

    public Control(Panel1 p1, Panel2 p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;  
   //Añades como evento el actionPerformed de abajo a los botones.
        p1.Boton1.addActionListener(this);
        p2.Boton2.addActionListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve) {
        if (eve.getSource().equals(p1.Boton1)) {
            p1.Boton1.setEnabled(false);
            p2.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (eve.getSource().equals(p2.Boton2)) {
            p1.Boton1.setEnabled(true);
            p2.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
//main para ejecutar el programa
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
        Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
        Control c = new Control(p1, p2);
    }
}
```